# DXL - Unexpected character output

Tags: character-encoding, ibm-doors

I'm writing a function to replace substrings (what laguange doesn't have this, grr), and I am getting some strange characters in my ouput. I cannot figure out why.

```
string replaceSubstring(string input, string targetSubstring, string substitute, bool matchCase)
{
    string result = input
    Buffer b = create
    b = input
    int targetStartPos
    int targetLength

    while (findPlainText(result, targetSubstring, targetStartPos, targetLength, matchCase))
    {
        string prefixStr = b[0:targetStartPos - 1]
        string suffixStr = b[targetStartPos + targetLength:]

        b = prefixStr substitute suffixStr
        result = tempStringOf(b)
    }

    delete b
    return result
}
```

When running `print replaceSubstring("Jake Lewis", "ake", "ack", false)`, I get an output of `�*��*�is`. This would appear to be some sort of encoding issue, but I am unclear on how this is happening, or how to fix it.

Comment: Forgot to add, but I'm obviously expecting an output of "Jack Lewis"

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but maybe this helps with the next function you miss -- there are already implementations available, see https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014891187 and http://www.capri-soft.de/blog/?p=832.

Comment: Wow, these are lifesavers, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `stringOf()` instead of `tempStringOf()`. Your processing is fine, but the result becomes invalid after deleting `b`.